# trouble with Async.js for Node.JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, async.js

im trying to fight against the callback hell but im having trouble with my code.

Someone knows how to implement async.js to a structure like this:

```
for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
 //do something
 for(var j=0;j<array2.length;j++){
  //do something
  for(var k=0;k<array3.length;k++){
   //do something
   bd.findSomethig(array3[k].id, function(err, result){

   });

   bd.findSomethig(array3[k].ref, function(err, result){

   });

  }
 }
}
```

UPDATE:

i will put here the real structure i need to implement

```
     var array1 = array;
      var rsp=[];
        for(var i=0;i<array1.length;i++){
          var object1 = new Object();

          object1.a="xx";
          object1.b="xx";
          object1.c="xx";
          object1.d="xx";

            var array2=array1[i].array2;

            var array2Result=[];
            for(var j=0;j<array2.length;j++){

              var object2 = new Object();

                object2.a="xx";
                object2.b="xx";
                object2.c="xx";
                object2.d="xx";

              var array3=array1[i].array2[j].array3;
              var array3Result=[];

              for(var k=0;k<array3.length;k++){

               var object3 = new Object();
               var array4=array1[i].array2[j].array3[l].array4;
                var array3Result4=[];

                for(var l=0;l<array4.length;l++){

                  var object4 = new Object();
                  var array5=array1[i].array2[j].array3[k].array4[l].array5;

                  for (var m=0;m<array5.length;m++){
                    if(someConditional){

                        object4.a="xx";
                        object4.b="xx";
                        object4.c="xx";
                        object4.d="xx";

                        //Here i need to call a BD function to find some rows i need to build the JSON response
                          bd.findSomethig(array5[m].id, function(err, result){
                              object4.e=result;
                           });

                           bd.findSomethig(array5[m].ref, function(err, result){
                              object4.f=result;
                           });

                        array3Result4.push(object4);
                    }

                  }
                object3.a=segments;
                array3Result.push(object3);
              }
                object2.e=array3Result;
              array2Result.push(object2)              
            }
            object1.e=array2Result;
            rsp.push(object1);
          }
```

Comment: just remove two outer loops.

Comment: all loops are important. because i need iterate every time

Comment: They was three different arrays :( need to change answer...

Comment: yes, i updated the ask to be more clear. Because in the original post maybe you think are diferent arrays

Comment: Just nest `async.each`/`async.map` (or `…series`, or whatever you need) just like you did nest the loops. What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is, i dont know how to get the BD response and push the arrayResult4 with that information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In common your code will looks like this:

```
async.map(array1, function(item, next){
   var modifiedItem = modify(item);
   next(null, modifiedItem);
}, function(err, results){
   // results is an array of modifiedItem's here
});
```

To good readability you have to not write it as is.
Instead you are define some functions, which modify items and calls `next` callbacks.
This functions called as `iterators`.

For example:

```
function doubleIterator(item, next) {
  next(null, 2*item);
}

async.map([1,2,3], doubleIterator, function (err, results) {
  // we have results = [2, 4, 6] here
});
```

Also, we can to generate iterators depends our needs:

```
function getFieldIterator(field) {
   return function (item, next) {
      next(null, item[field]);
   }      
}
async.map([{id: 1}, {id: 7}], getFieldIterator('id'), function(err, results){
  // results = [1, 7]
});
```

For apply multidimensional structures we can to call `async` methods from our iterators:

```
   function getMapIt(iterator) {
     return function(item, next) {
       async.map(item, iterator, next);
     };
   }


async.map([[1, 2], [3, 4]], getMapIt(doubleIterator), function(err, results){
  // getMapIt returns iterator which receive two arrays
  // it run async.map on each of them
  // and apply doubleIterator in each
  // so, we have results = [[2, 4], [6, 8]] here
})
```

---

With updated question.
Here we just build our iterator and then run :)

```
async.map(array1, mapIterator(mapIterator(searchIterator)), callback);
// assume you have just 3-dimensional array
function mapIterator(iterator) {
  return function(item, next) {
    async.map(item, iterator, next);  
  }
}

//with structure in your question:
function mapField(field, iterator) {
  return function(item, next) {
    async.map(item[field], iterator, next);  
  }
}
// and use it as
// mapField('array2', mapField('array3', searchIterator))

function searchIterator(item, next) {
   async.parallel({
     id: search(item.id),
     ref: search(item.ref)
   }, next);       
}
function search(id) {
  return function(next){
    bd.findSomethig(id, next);
  }
}
function callback(err, results) {
  if (err) return console.error(err);
  console.log('Batch of results: ',results);
  // It should be represented same of array1 structure:
  /*
  [
    [
       [{id: dbRes, ref: dbRes}, {id: dbRes, ref: dbRes}],
       [{id: dbRes, ref: dbRes}, {id: dbRes, ref: dbRes}],
       [{id: dbRes, ref: dbRes}, {id: dbRes, ref: dbRes}]
    ],
    [
       [{id: dbRes, ref: dbRes}, {id: dbRes, ref: dbRes}],
       [{id: dbRes, ref: dbRes}, {id: dbRes, ref: dbRes}]
    ]

  ]
  */

}
```

May be need to play with limits here...
But concept of build this should be clear now.

Comment: still have no idea how to implement.. I need iterate in 5 arrays and build a JSON to return to client, in the last array i need make a query to the BD and the result will be a value in the JSON to return. I tryed to nested "async.each" 5 times but i think thats not recommend

Comment: `each` is just a loop. If you want to build result with your data you need a `map`. What is 5 arrays? `array1[i1][i2][i3][i4][i5] = {id: 1, ref: 3}`? If yes, than just build longer iterator: `mI(mI(mI(mI(searchIterator))))` For this case you may want to write nested iterator builder.

Comment: It's not a service for doing your work. What exactly you can't understand in my code example? Follow [mcve]

Comment: i cant see how you iterate in arrays and recovery te information from each to push in the new array.

Comment: I add some explanations to start of my answer

Comment: Thanks bro, i got the solution. Finally used 4 iterators. 50 points to gryffindor :D